# using static Regex.IsMatch vs creating an instance of Regex

Tags: c#, regex, optimization

In C# should you have code like:

```
public static string importantRegex = "magic!";

public void F1(){
  //code
  if(Regex.IsMatch(importantRegex)){
    //codez in here.
  }
  //more code
}
public void main(){
  F1();
/*
  some stuff happens......
*/
  F1();
}
```

or should you persist an instance of a Regex containing the important pattern? What is the cost of using Regex.IsMatch? I imagine there is an NFA created in each Regex intance. From what I understand this NFA creation is non trivial.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In a rare departure from my typical egotism, I'm kind of reversing myself on this answer.

My original answer, preserved below, was based on an examination of version *1.1* of the .NET framework.  This is pretty shameful, since .NET 2.0 had been out for over three years at the time of my answer, and it contained changes to the `Regex` class that significantly affect the difference between the static and instance methods.

In .NET 2.0 (and 4.0), the static `IsMatch` function is defined as follows:

```
public static bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern){
    return new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None, true).IsMatch(input);
}
```

The significant difference here is that little `true` as the third argument.  That corresponds to a parameter named "useCache".  When that is true, then the parsed tree is retrieved from cached on the second and subsequent use.

This caching eats up most—but not all—of the performance difference between the static and instance methods.  In my tests, the static `IsMatch` method was still about 20% slower than the instance method, but that only amounted to about a half second increase when run 100 times over a set of 10,000 input strings (for a total of 1 million operations).

This 20% slowdown can still be significant in some scenarios.  If you find yourself regexing hundreds of millions of strings, you'll probably want to take every step you can to make it more efficient.  But I'd bet that 99% of the time, you're using a particular Regex no more than a handful of times, and the extra millisecond you lose to the static method won't be even close to noticeable.

Props to [devgeezer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838615/36388), who pointed this out almost a year ago, although no one seemed to notice.

My old answer follows:

---

The static `IsMatch` function is defined as follows:

```
public static bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern){
    return new Regex(pattern).IsMatch(input);
}
```

And, yes, initialization of a `Regex` object is not trivial.  You should use the static `IsMatch` (or any of the other static `Regex` functions) as a quick shortcut only for patterns that you will use only once.  If you will reuse the pattern, it's worth it to reuse a `Regex` object, too.

As to whether or not you should specify `RegexOptions.Compiled`, as suggested by Jon Skeet, that's another story.  The answer there is: it depends.  For simple patterns or for patterns used only a handful of times, it may well be faster to use a non-compiled instance.  You should definitely profile before deciding.  The cost of compiling a regular expression object is quite large indeed, and may not be worth it.

---

Take, as an example, the following:

```
const int count = 10000;

string pattern = "^[a-z]+[0-9]+$";
string input   = "abc123";

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine("static took {0} seconds.", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    rx.IsMatch(input);
Console.WriteLine("instance took {0} seconds.", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    rx.IsMatch(input);
Console.WriteLine("compiled took {0} seconds.", sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
```

At `count = 10000`, as listed, the second output is fastest.  Increase `count` to `100000`, and the compiled version wins.

Comment: If the regex will be reused will not the compilation cost be greatly outweighed by the cost of re-parsing the regex on repeated use?

Comment: The regex is not reparsed on every use if a single instance is used.  It would only be reparsed if you use a new instance each time (as would happen if you use the static function).

Comment: Let's say you store your regex object in a static readonly variable in a long-lived application. If we ignore start-up time (by moving sw.Start() after the regex constructor), the compiled regex actually executes an order of magnitude faster in your test code

Comment: Not to be flippant, but then you might as well just move the entire loop before sw.Start(), and call it all start-up time.  Run-time cost is run-time cost.  Making the user wait while something initializes is the same as making the user wait while something else executes.

Comment: And by the way, with **both** constructor calls outside the timer start, I get much less than an order of magnitude difference between compiled and not compiled at 10000 iterations on my machine. Not-compiled takes about 0.011, and compiled takes about 0.01.  At count=1000, compiled is again slower.

Answer (score 36):

If you're going to reuse the regular expression multiple times, I'd create it with `RegexOptions.Compiled` and cache it. There's no point in making the framework parse the regex pattern every time you want it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, what do you mean by cache it?  How would you do that?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f(v=vs.110).aspx explains more supplied to me by @RB here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490864/net-performance-large-csv-read-remap-write-remapped

Answer (score 15):

This answer is no longer correct in regard to versions of .NET that I have on my machine.
4.0.30319 & 2.0.50727 both have the following for IsMatch:

```
public static bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern)
{
  return new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None, true).IsMatch(input);
}
```

The 'true' value is for a constructor parameter called "useCache". All of the Regex constructors ultimately chain through this one, the statics call this one directly - passing in 'true'.

You read more on the BCL blog post about optimizing Regex performance highlighting the static methods' cache use [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/25/optimizing-regular-expression-performance-part-i-working-with-the-regex-class-and-regex-objects.aspx). This blog posts also cites performance measurements. Reading series of blog posts on optimizing Regex performance is a great place to start.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Jon and just to clarify it would look something like this:

```
static Regex regex = new Regex("regex", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Its also worthwile to look at the `RegexOptions` enum for other flags that can be helpful at times.

Answer (score 7):

There are many things that will affect the performance of using a regular expression.  Ultimately, the only way to find out the most performant in your situation is to measure, using as realistic a situation as possible.

The page on [compilation and reuse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f.aspx) of regular expression objects on MSDN covers this.  In summary, it says

1. Compiled regular expressions take time to compile, and once compiled will only have their memory released on `AppDomain` unloads. Whether you should use compilation or not will depend on the number of patterns you are using and how often they are used.
2. Static `Regex` methods cache the parsed regular expression representation for the last 15 (by default) patterns.  So if you aren't using many different patterns in your application, or your usage is sufficiently clustered, there won't be much difference between *you* caching the instance or the framework caching it.

Comment: I don't care if the thread *is* seven months old, this is the only answer that gets it right.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read [Jeff's post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000228.html) on compiling Regex.

As for the question, if you are asking this question it means that you are going to use it just once. So, it really does not matter as the Reflector's disassembly of Regex.IsMatch is:

```
public static bool IsMatch(string input, string pattern, RegexOptions options)
{
    return new Regex(pattern, options, true).IsMatch(input);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For an WinForm application I was working on we could define a regex on valid characters which would run on every keystroke and a validation for the text for any textboxes (data entry application), so I used a cache or compiled regexes such as

```
  private static Dictionary<string, Regex> regexCache = new Dictionary<string, Regex>(20);
```

Where the regex expression was the key.

Then I had a static function I could call when validating data:

```
public static bool RegExValidate(string text, string regex)
{
  if (!regexCache.ContainsKey(regex))
  {
    Regex compiledRegex = new Regex(regex,RegexOptions.Compiled);
    regexCache.Add(regex, compiledRegex);
  }
  return regexCache[regex].IsMatch(text);
}
```