# Check if string has space in between (or anywhere)

Tags: c#

Is there a way to determine if a string has a space(s) in it?

`sossjjs sskkk` should return `true`, and `sskskjsk` should return false.

`"sssss".Trim().Length` does not seem to work.

Comment: Does String.Contains(" ") not work for you?

Comment: Please don't post multiple questions about the same thing. The duplicate question, which you also asked, has examples of using `Contains` and `IndexOf` to solve this. (And just ignore that last answer...)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If indeed the goal is to see if a string contains the actual *space* character (as described in the title), as opposed to any other sort of whitespace characters, you can use:

```
string s = "Hello There";
bool fHasSpace = s.Contains(" ");
```

If you're looking for ways to detect whitespace, there's several great options below.

Comment: For someone trying not to use magic strings this is not a solution.

Comment: This is truly the best solution, all you need to do to check for the space is use a if then statment.

Comment: This solution doesn't account for other white space characters like Tab, CR, LF etc.

Answer (score 156):

How about:

```
myString.Any(x => Char.IsWhiteSpace(x))
```

Or if you like using the "method group" syntax:

```
myString.Any(Char.IsWhiteSpace)
```

Comment: Useful to detect all type of spaces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: Can be shortened to `if ( myString.Any ( Char.IsWhiteSpace ))` and is slightly more readable.

Comment: This really should be the accepted anwer, there is no telling of how many weird whitespace characters are out there and this will work with everything .NET understands

Comment: @DougSeelinger Resharper really works wonders ;)

Comment: I think this is a fantastic answer (`+1` from me!) but I don't believe it's _more right_ than my own.  The question was _how to tell if a string has a space in it_, not _how to tell if a string contains any white space_.  For example, "Hello\tthere" does not contain a space, but it does contain whitespace characters.

Comment: In a portable library I had to use `myString.ToCharArray().Any(Char.IsWhiteSpace)`

Comment: Don't use the method group syntax. On a hot path, that piece of code comes with horrendous performance penalties due to [delegate allocations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/know-thine-implicit-allocations/).

Answer (score 13):

It's also possible to use a regular expression to achieve this when you want to test for any whitespace character and not just a space.

```
var text = "sossjj ssskkk";
var regex = new Regex(@"\s");
regex.IsMatch(text); // true
```

Comment: You could also use the static `Regex.IsMatch(text, @"\s")`

Comment: If you're doing a lot of compares then it is worth using the instance version but for the general case the static `Regex.IsMatch()` is more than adequate http://stackoverflow.com/a/414411/132599.

Answer (score 5):

`Trim()` will only remove leading or trailing spaces.

Try [`.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) to check if a string contains white space

```
"sossjjs sskkk".Contains(" ") // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

This functions should help you...

```
bool isThereSpace(String s){
    return s.Contains(" ");
}
```