# C# Regex Performance very slow

Tags: c#, regex

I am very new in regex topic. I want to parse log files with following regex:

```
(?<time>(.*?))[|](?<placeholder4>(.*?))[|](?<source>(.*?))[|](?<level>[1-3])[|](?<message>(.*?))[|][|][|](?<placeholder1>(.*?))[|][|](?<placeholder2>(.*?))[|](?<placeholder3>(.*))
```

A log line looks like this:

```
2001.07.13 09:40:20|1|SomeSection|3|====== Some log message::Type: test=sdfsdf|||.\SomeFile.cpp||60|-1
```

A log file with appr. 3000 lines takes very long to parse it. Do you have some hints to speed up the performance? Thank you...

**Update:**
I use regex because I use different log files which do not have the same structure and I use it that way:

```
string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
Regex pattern = new Regex(LogFormat.GetLineRegex(logFileFormat));

foreach (var line in fileContent)
{
   // Split log line
   Match match = pattern.Match(line);

   string logDate = match.Groups["time"].Value.Trim();
   string logLevel = match.Groups["level"].Value.Trim();
   // And so on...
}
```

**Solution:**
Thank you for help. I've tested it with following results:
1.) Only added RegexOptions.Compiled:
**From 00:01:10.9611143** to 00:00:38.8928387
2.) Used Thomas Ayoub regex
From 00:00:38.8928387 to 00:00:06.3839097
3.) Used Wiktor Stribiżew regex
From 00:00:06.3839097 **to 00:00:03.2150095**

Comment: Why do you use Regex for this? It seems that you could just use `String.Split` to get the array of columns.

Comment: Unless you really need to select this type of rows (with digits in a specific column), you really could use `String.Split()`. Else, replace all `.*?` with `[^|]*`, and you may also get some more speed with replacing `[|][|][|]` with `[|]{3}`. Actually, even if you need to check if some specific column value is numeric, you can do that with a non-regex piece of code...

Comment: You haven't shown us how you are actually matching the regex - please add in the relevant code.

Comment: Oh yes, the regex object - if a non-static method is used - should be created outside of the loop.

Comment: The character class `[|]` seems an inefficient way of getting one character. The regex engine might optimise it to a single explicit character, but it might not. I would replace them by `\|` throughout.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let me "convert" my comment into an answer since now I see what you can do about the regex performance.

[As I have mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470506/c-sharp-regex-performance-very-slow/39478212#comment66260500_39470506), replace all `.*?` with `[^|]*`, and also all repeating `[|][|][|]` with `[|]{3}` (or similar, depending on the number of `[|]`. Also, do not use nested capturing groups, that also influences performance!

```
var logFileFormat = @"(?<time>[^|]*)[|](?<placeholder4>[^|]*)[|](?<source>[^|]*)[|](?<level>[1-3])[|](?<message>[^|]*)[|]{3}(?<placeholder1>[^|]*)[|]{2}(?<placeholder2>[^|]*)[|](?<placeholder3>.*)";
```

Only the last `.*` can remain "wildcardish" since it will grab the rest of the line.

Here is a comparison of your and my regex patterns at [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester).

[image]

Then, use `RegexOptions.Compiled`:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(LogFormat.GetLineRegex(logFileFormat), RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: You can also use RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture instead removing nested capturing groups.

Comment: That makes sense since named groups will capture the relevant details.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the same regex multiple times, then make sure you compile it so that you are not recreating the regex each time. This can yield multiple orders of magnitude.

```
var regex = new Regex(".*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

The following LinqPad code shows 3 ways to use Regexes, from fastest to slowest.

The `regexFast` method takes about 5 seconds, the `regexSlow` method takes 6 seconds and the `regexSlowest` takes about 50 seconds.

```
void Main()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    var regex = @"(?<first>T[he]{2})\s*\w{5}.*";

    // This is the fastest method.
    sw.Restart();
    var regexFast = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
    {
        regexFast.Match("The quick brown fox");
    }
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();

    // This is a little slower - we didn't compile the regex so it has 
    // to do some extra work on each iteration.
    sw.Restart();
    var regexSlow = new Regex(regex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
    {
        regexSlow.Match("The quick brown fox");
    }
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();

    // This method is super slow - we create a new Regex each time, so 
    // we have to do *lots* of extra work.
    sw.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
    {
        var regexSlowest = new Regex(regex);
        regexSlowest.Match("The quick brown fox");
    }
    sw.Stop();
    sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.Dump();
}
```

Comment: You can also use Regex cache : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414328/using-static-regex-ismatch-vs-creating-an-instance-of-regex perf should be similar to your 2nd way

Answer (score 4):

Your regex can be optimized to:

```
(?<time>([^|]*))[|](?<placeholder4>([^|]*))[|](?<source>([^|]*))[|](?<level>[1-3])[|](?<message>([^|]*))[|]{3}(?<placeholder1>([^|]*))[|][|](?<placeholder2>([^|]*))[|](?<placeholder3>([^|]*))
```

using negated char class instead of lazy quantifiers. It reduce backtrack. Regex101 went from *316* steps to *47* with this change. Combine it with RB.'s answer and you should be fine

Comment: The `Compiled` will probably help, as RB said, but those  `.*?`s are the real problem.  I would get rid of the nested groups while I was at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GeneratedRegex source generator if you are using .NET7+. It can help drastically improve performance

```cs
[GeneratedRegex(@"<logFileFormat>")]
private static partial Regex LogFileRegex();
```

Comment: 1) Have you tested that it will in this case? 2) AFAIK it doesn't generate (much) more effective code then using `Compiled` option rather it improves the app starting time which can have significant benifit for "one invocation scenarios" like CLI tools, but this is not generally applicable.