# .NET Performance: Large CSV Read, Remap, Write Remapped

Tags: c#, io

I've done some research and found that the most efficient way for me to read and write multi-gig (+5GB) files is to use something like the following code:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs, 256 * 1024))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs, Encoding.ASCII, false, 256 * 1024))
{
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFile, true, Encoding.Unicode, 256 * 1024);
    string line = "";

    while (sr.BaseStream != null && (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Try to clean csv then split
        line = Regex.Replace(line, "[\\s\\dA-Za-z][\"][\\s\\dA-Za-z]", ""); 
        string[] fields = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        //I know there are libraries for this that I will switch out 
        //when I have time to create the classes as it seems they all
        //require a mapping class

        //Remap 90-250 properties
        object myObj = ObjectMapper(fields);

        //Write line
        bool success = ObjectWriter(myObj);
    }

    sw.Dispose();
}
```

CPU is averaging around 33% for each of 3 instances on an Intel Xeon 2.67 GHz. I was able to output 2 files in ~26 hrs that were just under 7GB while the process was running 3 instances using:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => new Worker().DoWork(args[0]),
    () => new Worker().DoWork(args[1]),
    () => new Worker().DoWork(args[2])
);
```

The third instance is generating a **MUCH** larger file being, *so far*, +34GB and am coming up on day 3, ~67 hrs in.

From what I've read, I think performance may be increased ***slightly*** by getting the buffer lowered to a sweet spot.

My questions are:

1. Based on what is stated, is this typical performance?
2. Besides what I mentioned above, are there any other improvements you can see?
3. Are the CSV mapping and reading libraries much faster that regex?

Comment: Use the profiler built into Visual Studio to identify hotspots. You might find, for example, that reusing a compiled regex will be a lot faster than creating a new one each time (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm not being rude by just providing a Google link but many more people have explained it's use much better than I will in a 450 character comment! https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=visual+studio+profiler and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: Good read, thanks @RB. If you can provide any insight if that's typical performance of creating large files, what you've given so far is enough to get me going in the right direction.

Comment: However, I would advise using a library (Linq2Csv is my favourite) - they will have done more profiling than you will, and might even be using a state machine rather than a regex, which is likely to be much faster. They will also handle edge-cases - like if there is a comma in one of your fields...

Comment: Ultimately though - you have to just try multiple ways, profile them all, and pick the fastest after you've optimised each one (but you will probably see  a significant speed-up by using a compiled regex as you are CPU-bound).

Comment: @RB Post what you've said in comments as answer and I'll accept as that will effect my question 1 and you've answered 2 & 3 for me.

Comment: Done - I've included precise details of how to fix the regex issue. Thinking about it, 7GB over 26 hours is incredibly slow - I would expect you to get an order of magnitude improvement assuming your hardware is a modern laptop with SSD and multicore processor.

Comment: The `StreamReader` is already buffered... is buffering it again giving you better speed?

Comment: @xanatos yes, I'm not sure if being explicit is making it faster or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first of all, you should profile your code to identify bottlenecks.

Visual Studio comes with a built-in profiler for this purpose, which can clearly identify hot-spots in your code.

Given that your process is CPU bound, this is likely to prove very effective.

However, if I had to guess at why it's slow, I would imagine it's because you are not re-using your regexes. A regex is relatively expensive to construct, so re-using it can see massive performance improvements.

```
var regex1 = new Regex("[\\s\\dA-Za-z][\"][\\s\\dA-Za-z]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var regex2 = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
while (sr.BaseStream != null && (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //Try to clean csv then split
    line = regex1.Replace(line, ""); 
    string[] fields = regex2.Split(line);
    //I know there are libraries for this that I will switch out 
    //when I have time to create the classes as it seems they all
    //require a mapping class

    //Remap 90-250 properties
    object myObj = ObjectMapper(fields);

    //Write line
    bool success = ObjectWriter(myObj);
}
```

However, I would strongly encourage you to use a library like Linq2Csv - it will likely be more performant, as it will have had several rounds of performance tuning, and it will handle edge-cases that your code doesn't.

Comment: Much faster so far. Thank you.